# Javascript lastIndex regex property to PHP regex

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I'm trying to translate a javascript script in PHP. So far is going good, but I stumbled across some code on which I'm clueless:

```
while (match = someRegex.exec(text)) {
    m = match[0];

    if (m === "-") {

       var lastIndex = someRegex.lastIndex,
           nextToken = someRegex.exec(parts.content);

       if (nextToken) {
              ...
       }

       someRegex.lastIndex = lastIndex;
    }
}
```

The `someRegex` variable looks like this:

```
/[^\\-]+|-|\\(?:[0-3][0-7]{0,2}|[4-7][0-7]?|x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}|c[A-Za-z]|[\S\s]?)/g
```

exec should be equivalent to preg_match_all in PHP:

```
preg_match_all($someRegex, $text, $match);
$match = $match[0];  // I get the same results so it works

foreach($match as $m){

   if($m === '-'){

     // here I don't know how to handle lastIndex and the 2nd exec :(

   }

}
```

Comment: Where does `parts` come from in the JavaScript?

Comment: It's an object with a few properties that is built with another regex. In PHP I made it an associative array (it looks the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use that `lastIndex` magic at all - essentially you're executing the regex twice on each index. If you really want to do that, you'd need to set the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag in [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) so that you can get the position, add capture length and use it as the next [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) offset.

Better use something like this:

```
preg_match_all($someRegex, $text, $match);
$match = $match[0]; // get all matches (no groups)

$len = count($match);
foreach($match as $i=>$m){

    if ($m === '-') {
        if ($i+1 < $len) {
            $nextToken = $match[$i+1];
            …
        }
        …
    }
    …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, exec is not equivalent to preg_match_all, as exec stops at the first match (the g modifier only sets the lastIndex value to loop through the string). It's equivalent to [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).
So you find the first match, get the value thanks to the $array argument, the offset of this value (contained in $flags) and continue your search by setting the offset (last argument).

I guess the second execution won't be a problem as you'll do exactly the same thing as in the javascript version.

Note that I haven't tried the loop, but it should be pretty straightforward once you've figured out how preg_match works exactly with the optional arguments (I'll run some test).

```
$lastIndex = 0;
while(preg_match($someRegex, $text, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $lastIndex) {
  $m = $match[0][0];
  $lastIndex = $match[0][1] + strlen($m); //thanks Bergi for the correction

  if($m === '-') {
            // assuming the $otherText relate to the parts.content thing
    if(preg_match($someRegex, $otherText, $secondMatch, 0, $lastIndex)) {
      $nextToken = $secondMatch[0];
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I guess that should be it (excuse any small error, haven't done php for a while).

Comment: `exec` alone is equivalent to `preg_match`, but it's being used in a while-loop, so it's essentially equivalent to `preg_match_all`.

Comment: It is if you forget the **nextToken = someRegex.exec(parts.content);**. He/she'd have an easier time looping with preg_match. Furthermore, he/she may need to do the second match right after the first.

Comment: Isn't it `$lastIndex = $match[0][1] + strlen($m);`?

Comment: It is, thanks for the correction, that 1 came from my test. Editing right away.